# Solr-java error: class com.restfb.types.Post declares multiple JSON fields named type

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, gson, illegalargumentexception, restfb

I'm trying to convert rest-facebook response to a Post class object as follows:

```
Post post = gson.fromJson(restFBResponse.toString(), Post.class);
```

where, `restFBResponse` is a post from Facebook. But it is resulting into error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.restfb.types.Post declares multiple JSON fields named type
```

I think this is due to:

```
1)
class Post extends NamedFacebookType{
  @Facebook
  private String type;
  //and some more class members
}

2)
class NamedFacebookType extends FacebookType {
  //few class members
}

3)
class FacebookType implements Serializable {
  @Facebook
  private String type;
  //and some more class members
}
```

So, `private String type;` is being declared twice, in `class Post` and `class FacebookType`.

1) If such re-declaration occurs in subclass,should it not be overridden? and

2) How can I overcome this error `class com.restfb.types.Post declares multiple JSON fields named type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just written my own class without extension, found no other better option..

```
public class MyPost{

    @Facebook
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess GSON suggested that

@SerializedName("type1")
private String type;

This may resolve issue. But I think there should be a cleaner solution to this..I found that the issue has been marked invalid and no further response was received.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own serializer and deserializer for gson to serialize and deserialize `Post` object.

While doing so use restfb's `DefaultJsonMapper` to map Post ob.

Something Like,

```
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .serializeNulls()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .registerTypeAdapter(Post.class, new PostDeserializer())
        .registerTypeAdapter(Post.class, new PostSerializer())
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .create();
private DefaultJsonMapper dMapper = new DefaultJsonMapper();

private class PostDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Post> {
        @Override
        public Post deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
                JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            Post post = dMapper.toJavaObject(jsonElement.toString(), Post.class);
            return post;
        }
    }

private class PostSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Post> {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Post post, Type type,
                JsonSerializationContext context) {
            return gson.toJsonTree(dMapper.toJson(post));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to declare the same variable "type" in your class Post. As it extends from FacebookType, it implicitly has the variable "type".

Solution:

```
Simply remove the sentence "private String type;" from your Post class
Replace the "private" word with "protected" in your "type" variable from your FacebookType
```

Comment: we cannot change class `FacebookType`. It's from Facebook api jar.